# API token authentication using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, api, authentication, token

Does anyone know how to authenticate a user using a api token with Apache HttpClient? I am able to connect to my api but I get a "couldn't authenticate you" error.

**HERE IS MY CODE**:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
  HttpClient client;
  client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("MY WORKING HTTPS URL IS HERE");
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
  String http_line = " ";

  while((http_line = rd.readLine()) != null)
  {
     System.out.println(http_line);
  }

}
```

**My api throws back this**:

```
<errors>
<error>Couldn't authenticate you</error>
</errors>
```

**And my Output console gives me this error**:

log4j: WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).

log4j: WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

log4j: WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

**ALSO** should I be using something other than HttpClient since my url is "https://" and not "http://"? I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1 (iOS).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, your console output and authentication error are completely unrelated. Secondly, without knowing anything about the API you mention, there is no way we can possibly help you other than to say that the API requires authentication and you clearly haven't given any sort of credentials.

Comment: @rmlan First off, I know my console output is unrelated. I was just seeing if someone could give me some insight as to what those errors meant. Secondly, "API token authentication using Apache HttpClient" is the title of my question. I don't know how to use authentication in Apache HttpClient using my given api token. That's what I was asking.

Comment: Well you haven't appeared to do any research on your own, so why not go do some research and try some things?

Comment: @rmlan actually I have done research and I have tried setCredentials(new AuthScope(), new UsernamePasswordCredentials()... That's how I knew there was a way to input a username and password but for security purposes I know using a token would be best.